# Returning a variable as a constructor function

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I was advised to read the book [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript). I was reading the factory design pattern and came across the following difficulty, just have a look at the below script:

```
// Types.js - Constructors used behind the scenes

// A constructor for defining new cars
function Car( options ) {

  // some defaults
  this.doors = options.doors || 4;
  this.state = options.state || "brand new";
  this.color = options.color || "silver";

}

// A constructor for defining new trucks
function Truck( options){
  this.state = options.state || "used";
  this.wheelSize = options.wheelSize || "large";
  this.color = options.color || "blue";
}


// FactoryExample.js

// Define a skeleton vehicle factory
function VehicleFactory() {}

// Define the prototypes and utilities for this factory

// Our default vehicleClass is Car
VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass = Car;

// Our Factory method for creating new Vehicle instances
VehicleFactory.prototype.createVehicle = function ( options ) {

  switch(options.vehicleType){
    case "car":
      this.vehicleClass = Car;
      break;
    case "truck":
      this.vehicleClass = Truck;
      break;
    //defaults to VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass (Car)
  }

  return new this.vehicleClass( options );

};

// Create an instance of our factory that makes cars
var carFactory = new VehicleFactory();
var car = carFactory.createVehicle( {
            vehicleType: "car",
            color: "yellow",
            doors: 6 });

// Test to confirm our car was created using the vehicleClass/prototype Car

// Outputs: true
console.log( car instanceof Car );

// Outputs: Car object of color "yellow", doors: 6 in a "brand new" state
console.log( car );
```

This is the example I found for the factory design pattern, now my problem is understanding the following line. Considering that vehicleClass class is defined as a variable:

```
VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass = Car;
```

I don't understand it being returned as a constructor function:

```
return new this.vehicleClass( options );
```

Well that's my only difficulty and running over the code again and again, still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: A function is being passed in as a variable (functions are first-class citizens in JS), and then called later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is returned here is not a function (you are right that it would not make sense). What is returned is a new object (see the `new` key word).

When you want to return a new object of type `Truck` than you would use the code:

```
return new Truck( options )
```

However in this specific case, the type of the vehicle you want is defined by the user. So `this.vehicleClass` refers to the value defined in the switch just above the return. In other words, `vehicleClass` will be replaced by `Car` (resp. `Truck`) if the users chose a `car` (resp. `Truck`).

The constructor that will be called will thus be either the `Car` or `Truck` constructor defined in the first lines of the code.

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Ur freaking awesome !! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer as valid, however I am not a Javascript expert (although I used it in a few occasions) and I think that the comments bellow should be read carefully. Especially concerning the fact that functions can be returned as objects in javascript. Hence although my answer might help to understand the problem it seems it is at least partially wrong when I state that "What is returned here is not a function".

Answer (score 1):

What You are assigning to `VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass` isn't an actual `class`, but a reference to a `constructor function`.

To create an object in JavaScript, the new operator must be followed by a constructor function. Since `VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass`, or later in the code `this.vehicleClass`, holds a reference to a constructor function, you can create a new vehicle object with `new this.vehicleClass(options)`.

One of the big advantages of JavaScript is the ability to pass functions as arguments, without the need of delegates.

I hope this makes it a little clearer.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript **Functions are objects**, so *they can be used as return values*. This means that a function doesn’t need to return some sort of data value or array of data as a result of its execution.

**A function can return another more specialized function**, or it can create another function on-demand, depending on some inputs.
Here’s a simple example: A function does some work, probably some one-off initialization, and then works on its return value. The returned value happens to be another function, which can also be executed:

```
var setup = function () {
   alert(1);
   return function () {
        alert(2);
   };
};
// using the setup function
var my = setup(); // alerts 1
my(); // alerts 2
```

Because *setup()* wraps the returned function, it creates a closure, and you can use this closure to store some private data, which is accessible by the returned function but not to the outside code. An example would be a counter that gives you an incremented value every time you call it:

```
var setup = function () {
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        return (count += 1);
    };
};
// usage
var next = setup();
next(); // returns 1
```

Source: [**JavaScript Patterns**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) By [**Stoyan Stefanov**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do#tab_04_2).

And in your case `return new this.vehicleClass( options );`, is returning a new object Calling the constructor `vehicleClass` .

Answer (score 1):

```
new <expression>(<arguments>)
```

is evaluated like this:

1. evaluate `<expression>`
2. call `new <result of 1>(<arguments>)`

That is, you can put any expression between `new` and the opening parenthesis, as long as this expression returns a function.

BTW, this code doesn't seem to do things in a right way. First, it defines a property on the prototype:

```
VehicleFactory.prototype.vehicleClass = Car;
```

Then, in `createVehicle`, it adds a local property with the same name:

```
this.vehicleClass = Car;
```

which effectively overrides the `prototype`'s `vehicleClass` in subsequent lookups:

```
 a = createVehicle(); // no `vehicleType` here, returns `Car`
 b = createVehicle({vehicleType: 'truck'}); // returns `Truck`
 c = createVehicle(); // no `vehicleType` here, but this time it returns `Truck`???
```

A better way to design `createVehicle` would be like this:

```
VehicleFactory.prototype.createVehicle = function ( options ) {
  var klass;    

  switch(options.vehicleType){
    case "car":
      klass = Car;
      break;
    case "truck":
      klass = Truck;
      break;
  }

  return new (klass || this.vehicleClass)( options );

};
```

On a subjective note, "design patterns" are not very idiomatic in javascript, if you want another reading recommendation, give [JavaScript Allongé](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read) a try.